# Permissions corrupted?

Tags: linux, filesystems, permissions, osx

A few weeks ago, I installed Linux Mint on a USB flash drive. I used it to copy the contents of my HFS+ external hard drive to my Windows drive on my desktop. Then, I formatted the external drive to install linux on it, as well as create a large HFS+ partition. I copied the contents back from the windows drive to the new HFS+ partition on the external drive. Now, half of the files' permissions are acting weird. For example, on the drive, "/Files" is `drwxrwxrwx`, and if I copy something that's `-rw-r--r--@` from my Desktop on my Mac laptop into "/Files" on my external drive, it remains `-rw-r--r--@`, but I can't rename, modify, or delete it. Why might this be? I do not have admin/root access on my mac, but I do on my Linux install. I've run "chmod -R 777" on the entire drive on my linux install, and I can modify these files there, but the permissions still act weird when it's on my Mac. Is this because there are different users and groups on my Mac?

Comment: What is the owner and group of the files?  What does the full `ls -l` output look like (a single line should be enough).

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx   6 student  staff        204 Jul 27 12:01 Files` for the "Files" folder, `-rwxrwxrwx  1 student  staff   12521940 Jul 27 11:22 cra.aes` for a file in Files I can't rename. I'm on a school-owned computer at home, the main (non-system) accounts are "student", "teacher", "parent", and "admin" (root disabled, I believe). I'm "student", and I'm not sure who's in "staff" ("teacher" and "admin, I believe, but it might include "parent" for simplicity).

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you write down (bullet points) each drives you have, and for each (sub-bullet) the partitions and file systems used. Then you tell us on which drive and partition you have OS X and Linux installed, and on which drive and partition you have problem with permissions. It is not enough to tell us the permissions on /Files, you have to tell us if this is a mount point or a sub-directory from a mount point (and to which drive/partition it is attached). Then give us the output of `ls -ln` and of `id` (on both OS X and Linux). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a mode line, '@' usually means extra attributes, and '+' means extra permissions. OS X uses both of these extensively, whereas Linux tends not to (especially for permissions).

On OS X, you can view these using `ls -le@`, where `-l` is long output, `-e` shows access control, and `-@` shows extra flags (some of which may prevent modification to a file even if its permissions allow it).

On Linux, you can view attributes with `lsattr` or `lsattr -l` (long output, more human-friendly). Then you can change them, if needed, using `chattr`. In particular, you may be interested in the `i` (immutable) attribute, which prevents modifications to files.

You can deal with Linux ACLs using the `getfacl` and `setfacl` commands, but you may have to install those tools, and your filesystem may not support them anyway.